# Problema ao levantar API e realizar requisição via Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Estou criando um projeto de API em dotnet core e não estou conseguindo realizar requisições via postaman nela.

Urls de tentativas:

```
"http://localhost:5050 e http://0.0.0.0:5050"
"https://localhost:5001 e https://0.0.0.0:5001"
"http://localhost:5000 e http://0.0.0.0:5000"
```

Request:

```
{
  "UserName": "testeteste",
  "Name": "Teste Teste",
  "Email": "teste@live.com",
  "Password": "Teste1234",
  "Password2": "Teste1234"
}
```

Repositorio: `https://github.com/nicolabogar/Aplicacao-Gerenciar-Senhas`

Configurei uma URL `"http://0.0.0.0:5050"` padrão em Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)            
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5050");
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
        })
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())            
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builder, configuration) => 
        {                
            configuration.Sources.Clear();
            configuration.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
            configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true);
        });
}
```

Realizei as devidas configurações na classe Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAppSettings(Configuration);
        services.AddControllers();            
        services.AddSingletons();
        services.AddScopes();
        services.AddEntityFramework();
        services.AddAuthenticationJwt();
        
        services.AddLogging((config) =>
        {
            config.AddDebug();
            config.AddConsole();
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        
        app.UseRouting();
        
        //app.UseAuthorization();
        //app.UseAuthentication();
        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Você deve especificar qual controller está chamando, você tentou a seguinte URL?

```
http://localhost:5050/api/Usuario/CriarUsuario
http://0.0.0.0:5050/api/Usuario/CriarUsuario
```

O `UserUrls` serve para:

> Defina como uma lista separada por ponto e vírgula (;) de prefixos de URL aos quais o servidor deve responder. Por exemplo, http://localhost:123. Use "*" para indicar que o servidor deve escutar solicitações em qualquer endereço IP ou nome do host usando a porta e o protocolo especificados (por exemplo, http://*:5000). O protocolo (http:// ou https://) deve ser incluído com cada URL. Os formatos compatíveis variam dependendo dos servidores.

[Fonte](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score -3):

Uma boa forma de puderes validar que tipo de requests podes fazer na tua aplicação será sempre habilitares e configurares o uso do Swagger na tua API.

[Fonte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)